# schema.xml changes from Solr4 to Solr5

Tags: field, solr4, solr5

I'm migrating from Solr 4.6.0 to 5.4.0. We opted to use our old schema.xml instead of using the managed_schema because we have quite a few copyFields. Starting up solr server, we got this error:

> Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_general": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilterFactory'

On googling, we saw that StopFilterFactory is not deprecated yet. What could be the problem?

Also there's no comprehensive guide on how to use a schema from Solr4 in Solr5. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Not sure about Solr 5.X.X but solved above issue in Solr 6.1.0 by
removing `enablePositionIncrements="true"` from schema xml.
Solr may throw another error

```
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "edge_ngram": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class:'org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramFilterFactory'
```

Removing `side="front"` from schema file will remove this error as well.

Comment: Removing all `enablePositionIncrements` parameters from my schema.xml file solved the problem.  There were approx. 20 occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have resolved your error.

There will be some major changes between Solr 4.6.0 and 5.4.0, and I think your error is due to the changes between the 2 different versions. It means your schema.xml is outdated and won't work for SOlr 5.4.0.

I suggest you doing the following:

When you install Solr 5.4.0 and create a new core, Solr will create a managed-schema file in the conf directory of the core directory. I suggest you compare managed-schema file to your old `schema.xml` file. For example, look for `fieldType name="text_general"` in your old `schema.xml`, and see the difference between the contents under `fieldType name="text_general"` and the contents under `fieldType name="text_general"` of managed-schema of Solr 5.4.0. One potential way to fix the error is by removing `enablePositionIncrements="true"` as Neeraj suggested above.

After the fix for the contents under `enablePositionIncrements="true"`, if Solr gives another error regarding your old `schema.xml`, look for the location of your error in `schema.xml` and compare it to managed-schema as done above.

Don't forget to remove or move managed-schema file out of the `conf` directory since the managed-schema probably won't be something you want to use. You would want to use your old `schema.xml`, right?

Hope this helps.